# Answer question or improve code?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow

In SO there's quite a few new programmers posting bits of (copy & pasted) code they're having issues with, riddled with problems that, while not relevant to the question, are issues they will eventually likely post a new question for.

Should we just answer the question in this case or go into a full on code review session to help the poster with programming rather than just the specific question?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

General rule is, **when answering a question you must *answer the question.***

If you also do other things - critique the rest of their code, suggest other strategies for improvement, comment on the nice weather we're having lately - so be it.

But first and foremost, **answer the question.** Without that, what you're posting isn't really an answer, and may well be deleted.